Orbit of automorphism group of projective space acts on point
Let $k$ be an infinite field and $G:=\text{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^n_k)$. Let $x\in \mathbb{P}^n_k$ be any point which is not generic point, is true that the subset $\Theta_x:=\lbrace\tau(x)\mid\tau\in G\rbrace$ is an infinite set?

What if $x$ is the general point?

yeah we should exclude generic point, thanks for point out

@Vector Points for the pun :)  You should use $\text{Aut}$
